Is it possible to use soft-close hinges from a new toilet seat on our existing seat?
Our toilet is light green and it has a light green seat. We would like to convert the seat to slow closing and not purchase a white seat. Can we use the mechanism from a new seat to make the green seat slow closing?

You haven't provided enough detail for us to answer. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then do so.

Without more detail, all we can say is "maybe, if the mounting positions and weights are comparable. Try it? "

why not just buy a light green slow close - https://www.homedepot.ca/product/bemis-round-plastic-toilet-seat-with-whisper-close-and-easy-clean-change-hinge-in-ming-green/1000835620?eid=PS_GOOGLE_D00_Corporate_GGL_Shopping_All-Products_All%20Products__PRODUCT_GROUP_pla-294357559827&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsPXx5Mv9iAMVgQ2tBh2Gmi5oEAQYBSABEgJtzPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

If your old green seat/lid has a hinge assembly that is attached to the seat/lid with screws, and the target soft-closing seat also has a hinge assembly that is attached to the seat/lid with screws, you should be fine to swap (even if the screw holes don't line up; drill new pilot holes and use caulk to fill unused holes).
Some toilet seats (particularly solid plastic units) have integrated hinge ears/loops/brackets. If either unit in question has these it is unlikely that components from one will fit the other.
